# compatibility and structure padding

Tags: c++, c, linux, windows

there is one structure in Linux (64bit OS)
And I did the following to output this structure as Hexa code.

After the below code, "strBuff" will be output to the file in the same way as "printf",
This is a situation that needs to be read from windows, and should be stored in the same structure as above "example".
However, there was a problem here.
In my current windows, unsigned long size is 4byte.
In my current Linux, unsigned long size is 8byte.

So there is too much zero output in the output text.
This seems to be related to the padding bit. It is expected that only 2 bytes should be padding, and padding is done by 4 bytes.
It is not possible to change the structure "example" because the code is implemented by thinking it is 4byte when outputting from linux and the code is already in the completion stage.

I have two things to ask.

1. What if I need to get rid of unnecessary zero hexa in the output code?
   Currently, we are using a hard coding method to skip all unsigned long and signed long variables.
2. Compatibility between windows and linux should be solved.

The code can be changed both on the reading side and on the output side. Is there a lib related to the above problem and compatibility that can solve the padding problem?

```
enter code here

struct example
{
unsigned long Ul; 
int a;
signed long Sl;
}

struct examle eg;

// data input at eg

char *tempDataPtr = (char*)(&eg);

for(int i = 0 ; i < size(example) ; i++)
{
sprintf(&strBuff[i*3],"%02X ", tempDataPtr[i]);
}
```

Comment: You're just creating trouble for yourself by not changing the structure.  If the code already works in Windows (where `long` and `int` are the same) then it should work perfectly well with the types corrected to be `int`.

Comment: ... but you should also be serializing the structure properly, not just outputting its internal representation.

Comment: @HarryJohnston 
That means if I can not change the structure, I need to skip the bits with hard cording to the output code for serialization. Am I right?.....

Comment: You shouldn't be working with the bits *at all*.  Treat each field in the structure as a field, e.g., print the value of Ul, then print the value of a, then print the value of Sl.  But you also need to think about what you're going to when the Linux version of the structure contains data that *can't* be contained in the Windows version of the structure.

Comment: @HarryJohnston 
Thank you for answer. I know what you mean.  then What better way to exclude that field?

Comment: Huh?  If you don't need the field, you exclude it by not printing it.  If you do need the field, you'll have to cast between the two different types.  That's only a problem when the value in the field is too big to fit in the other type.

Comment: @Harry Johnston Oh, I'm sorry. I was a beginner and I understood it like a fool. -_-   I'll just print out each fields and deal with problems that occur if the field is too big size.

Answer (score 1):

Use types that have explicit format:
(And order them from largest to smallest for good measure, to protect against padding discrepancies between fields)

```
struct example
{
    uint32_t Ul;
    int32_t Sl;
    int16_t a;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answer. 
I am a new employee who can not modify the structure. The format is already set and I can not modify it. I am sad.

Comment: I can not even change the order of struct variables. - _-;

Comment: Ah. How about copying from the structure you cannot change to a temporary well-behaved structure (and vice-versa on the reading side)?

Comment: You said in your question "the code can be changed" but here you say you can't. You don't want to directly serialize structs to do this if you need portability across compilers and platforms.

Comment: @Joe 
I apologize for the confusion first. There are only two places to read and write code, and I can not change the structure.